# Simple security for SQL Server LocalDB for local Windows application

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

A simple C# windows form application that uses a local SQL Server LocalDB (.mdf).

I want the end user to install the SQL LocalDB and application and run it in that simple, but also want the DB to be secured with a password (Like the one that is used on SQL Compact (sdf)).

I couldn't find that option in (mdf DBs) without creating a login in the server that should be identical to the one in the connection string! Which is not user friendly!

Need help! thanks :)

Comment: So you never read up on contained databases in SQL Server? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929071.aspx - all you need is a 2014 version of localdb.

Comment: Thanks @TomTom, No I didn't, but is there an existing solution rather than migrating?

Comment: What do you mean with Migrating? And no, MS sort of assumes people dealing with databases read the documentation ;) Contained databases area very new feature - if you use an outdated localdb it NATURALLY will not support features added in later versions.

Comment: Containment has nothing to do with encryption.